# Unable to access fields in JSON

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, dart

In my flutter app, I am getting the following JSON input

```
{-MM_bcShjvWQcqvgWyPh: {email: anotherone@test.com, profile_pic: https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/yahoo-49-789855.png, user_role: supplier, userID: K9ioYyiEUQVVNjx0owwsaABCDEFG}}
```

This is how I am getting it

```
usersReference.orderByChild("userID").equalTo(uid).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot2)  {
   Map<dynamic, dynamic> map2 = snapshot2.value;
   print(map2);
});
```

This prints the data as i presented above.

However, if I try to access `map["profile_pic"]` or anything else like that, I get `null`. Why is this and how can i solve this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(map2["-MM_bcShjvWQcqvgWyPh"]["profile_pic"]);

// or

print(map2.values.first["profile_pic"]);
```